# Any way to hide the collection data for DB admins in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hope you can help me, for compliance reasons the admins of mongodb should not be able to access informations in a specific collection. The only one that should be able to "see" and retrieve information should be the user itself through an application. In other words:

User inserts a new document in the collection Products (through app) with prices for a product. Admins of the DB should not be able to view those prices that are confidential of the Users company.

Answer (score 2):

Use [client-side encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/) to make data unreadable by users with administrative privileges.

Comment: The problem is that knowing the encryption key wouldn't help since it would still be a breach of information when I'm being audited... The only person allowed to have access of information is the client...

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. Who knowing the encryption key wouldn't help whom with what?